# Why UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrame's user info is not correct when iphone hotspot will turn on?

Tags: ios, sdk, notifications, uikit

I added DropDown menu to my view controller. When it shows up i put it to front of my super view. If i turn on hotspot iphone's status bar will get double height and i should change origin of my DropDown menu, so i added Notification to observe `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrame` and `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrame`.

If i change orientation of screen, it will give me correct user info like this:

```
***WILL CHANGE STATUS BAR***
StatusBar size: (0.0, 0.0, 736.0, 20.0)
***WILL CHANGE STATUS BAR***
StatusBar size: (0.0, 0.0, 736.0, 20.0)
***DID CHANGE STATUS BAR***
StatusBar size: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 20.0)
REAL Statusbar height: 20.0
***DID CHANGE STATUS BAR***
StatusBar size: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
REAL Statusbar height: 0.0
```

Functions that is used:

```
  func didChangeStatusBar(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("***DID CHANGE STATUS BAR***")
    let infoDict = notification.userInfo as! [String: Any]
    let statusBarSize = (infoDict[UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    print("StatusBar size: \(statusBarSize)")
    print("REAL Statusbar height: \(UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)")

    let realHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
}

  func willChangeStatusBar(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("***WILL CHANGE STATUS BAR***")
    let infoDict = notification.userInfo as! [String: Any]
    let statusBarSize = (infoDict[UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    print("StatusBar size: \(statusBarSize)")
  }
```

Also i don't know why it's called twice. 
Now i turn on hotspot on my iphone and use another one to connect, after status bar's height will double. Output is:

```
***WILL CHANGE STATUS BAR***
StatusBar size: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 40.0)
***DID CHANGE STATUS BAR***
StatusBar size: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 20.0)
REAL Statusbar height: 40.0
```

Did u see, that user info gave us value of status bar's height equal 20, but real height is 40. So i can't rely on this value to arrange my views. Is it a bug or i misunderstood something?